# 8th Wall XR for Unity: Saving RealityTexture to disk

Tags: unity-game-engine, 8thwall-xr

I'm trying to save the camera's feed to a png using this code but it seems not to work correctly:

```
void RecordAndSaveFrameTexture()
{
    if (mXr.ShouldUseRealityRGBATexture())
    {
        SaveTextureAsPNG(mXr.GetRealityRGBATexture(), mTakeDirInfo.FullName + "/texture_" + mFrameInfo.mFrameCount.ToString() + ".png");
    }
    else
    {
        SaveTextureAsPNG(mXr.GetRealityYTexture(), mTakeDirInfo.FullName + "/texture_y_" + mFrameInfo.mFrameCount.ToString() + ".png");
        SaveTextureAsPNG(mXr.GetRealityUVTexture(), mTakeDirInfo.FullName + "/texture_uv_" + mFrameInfo.mFrameCount.ToString() + ".png");
    }

}

public static void SaveTextureAsPNG(Texture2D aTexture, string aFullPath)
{
    byte[] bytes = aTexture.EncodeToPNG();
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(aFullPath, bytes);
    Debug.Log("Image with Instance ID:" + aTexture.GetInstanceID() + "with dims of " + aTexture.width.ToString() + " px X " + aTexture.height + " px " + " with size of" + bytes.Length / 1024 + "Kb was saved as: " + aFullPath);
}
```

Testing on a Non-ArCore android I get black images (with random colored pixels) with the correct size of 480 x 640 pixels. With ArCore it's a 0kb black image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a image from these textures directly does not work properly as this data is passed through the `XRCameraYUVShader` and `XRARCoreCamera` before a valid image can be rendered.

One option is to create a custom version of the `XRVideoController` which provides access to the material used to render the camera feed. From there, your code could be modified as so:

```
void RecordAndSaveFrameTexture() {
  Texture2D src = xr.ShouldUseRealityRGBATexture()
      ? xr.GetRealityRGBATexture()
      : xr.GetRealityYTexture();

  RenderTexture renderTexture = new RenderTexture (src.width, src.height, 0, RenderTextureFormat.ARGB32);
  Graphics.Blit (null, renderTexture, xrMat);
  SaveTextureAsPNG(renderTexture, Application.persistentDataPath + "/texture.png");
}

public static void SaveTextureAsPNG(RenderTexture renderTexture, string aFullPath) {
  Texture2D aTexture = new Texture2D(renderTexture.width, renderTexture.height, TextureFormat.RGBA32, false);
  RenderTexture.active = renderTexture;
  aTexture.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, aTexture.width, aTexture.height), 0, 0);
  RenderTexture.active = null;

  byte[] bytes = aTexture.EncodeToPNG();
  System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(aFullPath, bytes);
}
```

Where `xrMat` is the material used to render the camera feed.

That will give an camera image *without* any Unity game objects. If you'd like game objects to be displayed in the saved image, you could override `OnRenderImage` to achieve that:

```
void OnRenderImage(RenderTexture src, RenderTexture dest) {
    if (shouldSaveImageFrame) {
      SaveTextureAsPNG(src, Application.persistentDataPath + "/_rgbatexture.png");
      shouldSaveImageFrame = false;
    }
    Graphics.Blit (src, dest);
}
```

Where `shouldSaveImageFrame` is a flag you've set elsewhere to prevent an image from being saved on every frame.

Comment: Thanks, the method works great. I added this code to my XrVideoController :
`public Material GetMaterial() { return xrMat; }`

and using the getter I brought the material to my own script which incorporated the code you suggested